# How to filter an array by finding elemets in array in angularJs?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm new to angularJs. I'm facing an issue where i need to filter an array (in ng-repeat) by finding the element in array.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="(class_list_key, class_list) in trialList | filter: {class_id:selected_class_option_arr}">
```

I tried the above code (which is wrong). Here `selected_class_option_arr` is an array having values by which i need to filter `trialList` array using `class_id`.

Array `selected_class_option_arr` is like this -

```
["Sat_09:00_AM_10:30_AM", "Fri_10:00_AM_11:00_AM"]
```

I tried to find but didn't got proper example as per my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a filter function in the ng-repeat and loop through the against array to filter out the required values:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="classList in trialList | filter: filterClass >
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.filterClass = function(classList) {
      for(var i=0; i < selected_class_option_arr.length; i++) {
          return classList.class_id.indexOf(selected_class_option_arr[i]) != -1 
     }  
};
```

Working Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/yQ7D9fwwitfMktOkGjF8?p=preview